# How to replace xml attributes

Tags: xslt

Editing attributes of XML through XSLT. this xml document have 10 to 15 attributes of this type.

```html
Example:

<class student="TUTORIAL" Book_type="science" num_pages="250" online_license="yes"  tag="online library"/>

result

<class student="TUTORIAL" Book-type="science" num-pages="250" online-license="yes"  tag="online library"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>

            <xsl:attribute name="Book-type">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Book_type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="num-pages">
                <xsl:value-of select="@num_pages"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="online-license">
                <xsl:value-of select="@online_license"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except (@Book_type|@num_pages|@online_license)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
Check this code if it is useful for you.
```

Answer (score 3):

First you convert all with identical transformtation

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

after that handle attribute as below

```
<xsl:template match="@*[contains(name(.), '_')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{translate(name(), '_', '-')}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
<class student="TUTORIAL" Book-type="science" num-pages="250" online-license="yes" tag="online library"/>
```

Comment: You could actually use the second template for ALL attributes, it would handle the attributes without a "_" in the name just fine (at least, if they aren't in a namespace).

Comment: Thank you Rupesh, could you please tell me how to use same code for multiple class nodes?

Comment: @Raghava, This script will convert multiple class node.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay for your suggestion.

Comment: @Rupesh, I am having namespace attached to the root node, which is coming to <class xmlns:ns0="http://test.com" ....    I want to remove that namespace from the class node, is there any possibility to do the same?

Comment: @Raghava, you can easily remove namspace by adding a template